# async/await in ASP.NET with synchronous Sql Server connection

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

Is there any real benefit of using async/await in an ASP.NET application if the only I/O calls are to a backend SQL Server database that is not using the ASYNC parameter in its connection string?

Comment: Is the SQL server scalable?

Comment: No, I am assuming a simple SQL Server instance without clustering. I have a strong suspicion that in this case it is pretty much useless to pollute the code base with async but I am looking for a tangible reason to confirm or a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `async` is not going to help you in your situation (that is, with a single SQL Server instance). This is assuming that most (or all) I/O-bound ASP.NET requests hit the database.

As I stated in my [intro to `async` on ASP.NET article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx):

> A decade ago, a common architecture was to have one ASP.NET Web server that talked to one SQL Server database back end. In that kind of simple architecture, usually the database server is the scalability bottleneck, not the Web server. Making your database calls asynchronous would probably not help; you could certainly use them to scale the Web server, but the database server will prevent the system as a whole from scaling.

In contrast, for Azure SQL (or even SQL Server clusters), `async` on ASP.NET may be beneficial. For even more scalable backends (NoSQL or web APIs), `async` is even more likely to be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I have been reading your articles the last few days, and they have been invaluable for my understanding of async and its history. This really confirms what I suspected and understood from them.